# unable to get the data value of ajax on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update the user votes into database. This below ajax codes returns correct rating datas. But, I'm unable to get the alert data on another page. In my car_user_rating.php page I have tried this `echo $post_rating = $_POST['performance_rating'];`. But it doesn't get the performance_rating data value.

I have checked my console. It returns the rating values (4). I'm confused why it doesn't get the data value?

**ajax request**

```
$(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
      performance_rating = $('input:radio[name=rating]:checked').val();
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?=CAR_USER_RATINGS?>",
        data: { performance_rating: performance_rating },
        success : function(data){
            alert(performance_rating)
         },
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should alert the `data` which you pass in `success: function()`

like

```
     success : function(response){
        alert(response);
     },
```

Comment: check your php page. is there code is enclosed by `<?php ..your code .. ?>`

Comment: no. I have this codes on my php page `<?php
 echo $post_rating = $_POST['performance_rating'];
 /*var_dump($get_rating);
 echo $sql = "UPDATE ".TBL_CAR_USER_RATINGS." SET performance = '$get_rating' WHERE model_id = '2'";
 die();
 mysql_query($sql, $CN) or die(mysql_error()); */
?>` inside the body tag

Comment: no it does not work that way.
Also you cant use tags in ajax response page!!!! IF tags are used then the tags are returned as answer.
DO what you want without tags but only php.
Also when you say echo in php page you basically replying to client.
So do echo only to the value you send. SO if you want your php to return rating it should only be as below:
car_return_Rating.php
<?php
echo $_POST['performance_rating'];
?>

When you do this your data will have the value of performance_rating

Comment: @Beginner you html tag are also response. the ajax will get all the content on your page. so echo only the desired output.

Comment: @SKRocks : that is my problem. I have tried echo $_POST['performance_rating'] on my php page. it doesn't return the result. I'm confusing...

Comment: just it alerts the html tags only

Comment: put your php page content here? and also check have you echo on correct page which call by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

use 'var' in submit handler, may it's because of scope:

```
var performance_rating = $('input:radio[name=rating]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your context so cant say exactly. Also i dont know if you are using exact same code as above or you have written teh above code in a hurry since there are mistakes there!!!

However Firstly try these

1. data: { "performance_rating": performance_rating },
2. url: `"<?php=CAR_USER_RATINGS?>"`  //you have forgotten php
3. success : function(data, testStatus, xhr){
                                    },
   and check each values of data, testStatus, xhr

Also what is the value of

1. performace_Rating before $.ajax
2. `"<?php=CAR_USER_RATINGS?>"` before $.ajax

Comment: oops i saw it now!!!!
Should "<?=CAR_USER_RATINGS?>" be as it is?? I tot you had missed out php and a variable before =?

Comment: no. I have defined a constant value like these `define("CAR_USER_RATING", "car_user_ratings.php");` . I think my problem is not in my url path

Comment: i have answered ur problem in the other comment. Your car_user_ratings.php is wrong. Btw is that php code inside your car_user_ratings.php?

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize. I could figure out from your comment that your php is as below:

> no. I have this codes on my php page  inside the body tag

```
 <?php  echo $post_rating = $_POST['performance_rating'];   
/*var_dump($get_rating);    echo $sql = "UPDATE ".TBL_CAR_USER_RATINGS." SET performance = '$get_rating' WHERE model_id = '2'";     die();  mysql_query($sql, $CN) or die(mysql_error()); */ ?>
```

This is present inside the body tag!!! Well if you are using body tag i presume you are using other html, header(optional) tags as well

For a ajax response page the reply to client should "ONLY" be the value you want to send back.
Having tags will result in the the ajax response containing these tags as well.
So if you want your ajax page to return performance rating do the below:

```
//car_return_Rating.php 

<?php echo $_POST['performance_rating']; ?>
```

If you have below code your response is shown below

```
 //car_Return_rating.php
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $_POST['performance_rating']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

then response i.e. data in success(data){}

will be equal to

```
data = "<html><body>4</body></html>"; //assuming 4 to be equal to $_POST['performance_rating'];
```

Comment: @Beginner - if the answer is fine, would be helpful if you accepted it or upvoted it!!!!